# MUI v5: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in '...\node_modules\@mui\styled-engine'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, web-frontend

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in '...\node_modules\@mui\styled-engine'
```

I got a compilation failed problem for using Material-UI in a ReactJS project
I check the @mui `node_modules` folder but can't fix the compilation bug. Anyone who have any idea please share with me.

Comment: You might need to run `yarn` to install missed packages.

Comment: thanks i have now solution for this bug

Answer (score 7):

Before using MUI, you should skim the [installation guide](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/) to see if there are any required packages that you might be missing. In v5, MUI drops the JSS styling library (actually just mark it as obsolete and plan to remove it in v6) in favor of [emotion](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion) as a default styling engine. If you don't use styled-component or any other third-party styling libraries and expect to use MUI right away, you still have to install emotion to use MUI styling API.

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

#### Related answer

- [MUI v5: Do I need to install @emotion/react or @emotion/styled to use sx prop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69673283/9449426)